How can i show buffering spinner in PlayerControlView in Exoplayer
Here is my code,by default it dont show buufer spinner,how can i add it
<androidx.media3.ui.PlayerControlView
    android:id="@+id/player_control_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:show_rewind_button="false"
    app:show_fastforward_button ="false"
    app:show_previous_button ="false"
    app:show_next_button ="false"
    app:animation_enabled ="true"
    app:ad_marker_width="100dp"
    app:show_vr_button="false"
    app:buffered_color="@color/white"

    />`

i changed in exo_player_control_view ,still not what i needed

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

androidx.media3.ui.PlayerControlView dont give a default buffer spinner,i want to add it

your question is not clear.
if you mean that you don't see a spinner try setting app:show_buffering="always"
if you mean that you cannot customize the spinner you can add a listener to the player and show/hide a custom spinner above the PlayerView
